# Shift only certain column right in dataframe, without overwritting existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this little issue I cannot get my head around. I have imported a rather messy csv which I initially created by converting a pdf to the said csv. Now, after some housekeeping (e.g. removing some rows containing unwanted string), I am left with a df that looks ALMOST ok.

```
Unnamed: 0 Benämning     Unnamed: 2   id      col1       col2       col3  \
0           1     item1  2090006400001  NaN  1 706,92  68 154,93  -2 730,37   
1           2     item2  2386135200002  NaN    789,38  31 520,02     554,14   
2           3     item3  7311041052112    C  1 935,00  29 495,95   9 015,04   
3           4     item4  7311041072226    C    778,00  27 207,10     915,71   
4           5     item5  2090213700000    C  1 189,70  24 888,11   9 450,73   

   col4   col5      col6       col7       col8   Col9   Col10     Col11  \
0   NaN  -4,49  1 706,92  68 154,93  -2 730,37  -4,49  243,85  9 736,42   
1   NaN   1,97    789,38  31 520,02     554,14   1,97  112,77  4 502,86   
2   NaN  34,23      0,00       0,00       0,00   0,00  276,43  4 213,71   
3   NaN   3,77    775,00  27 072,25     885,46   3,66  111,14  3 886,73   
4   NaN  42,53  1 189,37  24 881,63   9 449,00  42,53  169,96  3 555,44   

      col12  
0   -390,05  
1     79,16  
2  1 287,86  
3    130,82  
4  1 350,10
```

The only problem is that the columns `['Unnamed: 2','id','col1','col2','col3']` need to be shifted 1 step to the right. That is, the content of column ´´´Unnamed: 2`should be in column`id`,` id`in`Col1``` and so on. But, these are the only columns that need to be shifted. Everything else is fine.

`DF = DF.shift(axis=1)` shifts all columns right and thus not only missplaces columns that originally were positioned where they should but also overwrites the last columns.

Is there a method to do this nicely without having to split the dataframe, do the shifting and then reassemble it?

Thankful for any insight.

**Data**: I provide a dict if anyone wants to try a solution:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Benämning': {0: 'item1', 1: 'item2', 2: 'item3', 3: 'item4', 4: 'item5'},
 'Unnamed: 2': {0: 2090006400001,
  1: 2386135200002,
  2: 7311041052112,
  3: 7311041072226,
  4: 2090213700000},
 'id': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C'},
 'col1': {0: '1 706,92',
  1: '789,38',
  2: '1 935,00',
  3: '778,00',
  4: '1 189,70'},
 'col2': {0: '68 154,93',
  1: '31 520,02',
  2: '29 495,95',
  3: '27 207,10',
  4: '24 888,11'},
 'col3': {0: '-2 730,37',
  1: '554,14',
  2: '9 015,04',
  3: '915,71',
  4: '9 450,73'},
 'col4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'col5': {0: '-4,49', 1: '1,97', 2: '34,23', 3: '3,77', 4: '42,53'},
 'col6': {0: '1 706,92', 1: '789,38', 2: '0,00', 3: '775,00', 4: '1 189,37'},
 'col7': {0: '68 154,93',
  1: '31 520,02',
  2: '0,00',
  3: '27 072,25',
  4: '24 881,63'},
 'col8': {0: '-2 730,37', 1: '554,14', 2: '0,00', 3: '885,46', 4: '9 449,00'},
 'Col9': {0: '-4,49', 1: '1,97', 2: '0,00', 3: '3,66', 4: '42,53'},
 'Col10': {0: '243,85', 1: '112,77', 2: '276,43', 3: '111,14', 4: '169,96'},
 'Col11': {0: '9 736,42',
  1: '4 502,86',
  2: '4 213,71',
  3: '3 886,73',
  4: '3 555,44'},
 'col12': {0: '-390,05',
  1: '79,16',
  2: '1 287,86',
  3: '130,82',
  4: '1 350,10'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the columns and drop the 'Unnamed' one:

```
df[['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']] = df[['Unnamed: 2', 'id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
print(df.drop(columns='Unnamed: 2'))
```

if you don't want to worry about selecting the columns, use `loc` for automatic column alignment, but this will be slightly less efficient (need to shift all columns):

```
df.loc[:, ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']] = df.shift(axis=1)
print(df.drop(columns='Unnamed: 2'))
```

output:

```
   Unnamed: 0 Benämning             id col1      col2       col3       col4  \
0           1     item1  2090006400001  NaN  1 706,92  68 154,93  -2 730,37   
1           2     item2  2386135200002  NaN    789,38  31 520,02     554,14   
2           3     item3  7311041052112    C  1 935,00  29 495,95   9 015,04   
3           4     item4  7311041072226    C    778,00  27 207,10     915,71   
4           5     item5  2090213700000    C  1 189,70  24 888,11   9 450,73   

    col5      col6       col7       col8   Col9   Col10     Col11     col12  
0  -4,49  1 706,92  68 154,93  -2 730,37  -4,49  243,85  9 736,42   -390,05  
1   1,97    789,38  31 520,02     554,14   1,97  112,77  4 502,86     79,16  
2  34,23      0,00       0,00       0,00   0,00  276,43  4 213,71  1 287,86  
3   3,77    775,00  27 072,25     885,46   3,66  111,14  3 886,73    130,82  
4  42,53  1 189,37  24 881,63   9 449,00  42,53  169,96  3 555,44  1 350,10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` where you use a dict comprehension to shift column names one place to the right.

```
cols = ['Unnamed: 2','id','col1','col2','col3','col4']
df = df.rename(columns={i:j for i,j in zip(cols, cols[1:])}).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Per @jezrael (a cleaner way)

```
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(cols, cols[1:]))).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Unnamed: 0 Benämning             id      col2       col3       col4   col5  \
0           1     item1  2090006400001  1 706,92  68 154,93  -2 730,37  -4,49   
1           2     item2  2386135200002    789,38  31 520,02     554,14   1,97   
2           3     item3  7311041052112  1 935,00  29 495,95   9 015,04  34,23   
3           4     item4  7311041072226    778,00  27 207,10     915,71   3,77   
4           5     item5  2090213700000  1 189,70  24 888,11   9 450,73  42,53   

       col6       col7       col8   Col9   Col10     Col11     col12  
0  1 706,92  68 154,93  -2 730,37  -4,49  243,85  9 736,42   -390,05  
1    789,38  31 520,02     554,14   1,97  112,77  4 502,86     79,16  
2      0,00       0,00       0,00   0,00  276,43  4 213,71  1 287,86  
3    775,00  27 072,25     885,46   3,66  111,14  3 886,73    130,82  
4  1 189,37  24 881,63   9 449,00  42,53  169,96  3 555,44  1 350,10
```

Comment: `df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(cols, cols[1:])))` is better

Comment: The issue, is that now it's a bit tricky to remove the unwanted "col4"

Comment: @mozway right, we'll have to use `dropna` I guess

Comment: Yes, in this particular case ;), I'd use `how='all'`, though